# LNK2005 (already defined) – Linker behaves strange

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, boost, linker

We've stumbled upon a very obscure behaviour when linking. First the quite common linker error:

> error LNK2005: "**public: void __cdecl std::basic_ofstream<char,struct** 
>   **std::char_traits<char> >::`vbase destructor'(void)**" 
>   (**??_D?$basic_ofstream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QEAAXXZ**) already
>   defined in 
>   osgDBd.lib(osg80-osgDBd.dll)  d:\temp\osg_lnk2005_ofstream\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\libboost_unit_test_framework-vc110-mt-gd-
>   1_53.lib(unit_test_parameters.obj)

Demangled name for the lols:

> public: void __cdecl std::basic_ofstream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::`vbase destructor'(void) __ptr64

The situation: We are linking against boost unit test framework and Openscenegraphs' osgDB library and by introducing the line `std::ofstream out;` in our code we get the linker error above.

Here is the code,

```
#pragma comment(lib, "osgDBd.lib")
//#pragma comment(lib, "boost_unit_test_framework-vc110-mt-gd-1_53.lib") // dynamic: works
//#pragma comment(lib, "libboost_unit_test_framework-vc110-mt-sgd-1_53.lib") // fails, mixing static and dynamic crt
//#pragma comment(lib, "libboost_unit_test_framework-vc110-sgd-1_53.lib") // fails, mixing static and dynamic crt
#pragma comment(lib, "libboost_unit_test_framework-vc110-mt-gd-1_53.lib") 

/*
#define BOOST_PROGRAM_OPTIONS_DYN_LINK
#define BOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK
#define BOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK
*/
#include <fstream>

#include <osgDB/WriteFile>

#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::ofstream out;
    return 0;
}
```

(I resorted to pragma linking just for clarity in this sample)

When we link boost as static (but with dynamic CRT) the linker error above is generated, when the dynamic boost version is used, it vanishes.

All libs are compiled as debug with /MDd so no runtime mixing should occur.

While osgDB's fstream notes that only `osgDB::ofstream` should be used, I am not sure what causes this problem.

The fstream header of osg is here (if it matters):

```
namespace osgDB
{
    class OSGDB_EXPORT ofstream : public std::ofstream
    {
    public:
        ofstream();
        explicit ofstream(const char* filename,
            std::ios_base::openmode mode = std::ios_base::out);
        ~ofstream();

        void open(const char* filename,
            std::ios_base::openmode mode = std::ios_base::out);
    };
}
```

Is the root of all evil in this case the fact that boost is static and therefore brings it's dependencies into my executable? When boost is dynamic the import lib contains only exported symbols but when boost is static, everything is imported into my binary and then conflicting with the implicitly exported std::ofstream introduced by osgDB by dll-exporting the entire class?

Comment: Please escape `<>` symbols properly, HTML eats half of your error messages.

Comment: That osgDBd.lib import library looks pretty screwed up.  It should of course not export its own std::ofstream destructor.  Hard to guess how that happened, maybe it was built with /MT in effect.  Not good.

Comment: @HansPassant there is no compile guard for /MT and afaik the dll in dependency walker uses msvcrtd.dll so I assume it is /MDd

Comment: Just look for other victims, you find them at the project's forum.  [This one](http://forum.openscenegraph.org/viewtopic.php?t=12915&view=previous) looks like a good match.

Comment: @HansPassant I've read the comments there prior to posting here. /Force:Multiple dumbed the issue down to a warning but same as Vincent I refrained from using this in production and was somehow unsatisfied by the situation. That's why I hoped some in-depth explanation here as having osgDB linking with /Mt would cause much more issues, I suspect.

Comment: It is quite criminal at SO to not mention that you are already aware of the existing problem.  You are letting SO users waste a lot of time digging something up you already know about.  Getting the extra mileage out of them is exceedingly rare. Good luck with it.